# Add member to virtual collection using Entity Framerwork Core

Tags: entity-framework-core

I am trying to add a `Customer` to the `Customers` collection of a `CustomerCategory` but an exception is thrown with the message

> Database operation expected to affect 1 row(s) but actually affected 0
> row(s). Data may have been modified or deleted since entities were
> loaded.

I am using `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite Version 5.0.0` `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Proxies Version 5.0.0` in a `.NET 5.0` class library

I have tried to simplify the classes to help identify the cause of the error without success. This is what I have so far.

```
public class Customer
{
    public Guid CustomerId { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid();
    public Guid CategoryId { get; set; }
    public virtual CustomerCategory Category { get; set; }
    public string FileAs { get; set; }
}

public class CustomerCategory
{
    public Guid CategoryId { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid();
    public string CategoryCode { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
}

public class DataContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
    public DbSet<CustomerCategory> CustomerCategories { get; set; }
}

protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
{
    optionsBuilder.UseSqlite(DataService.SqliteConnectionString);
    optionsBuilder.UseLazyLoadingProxies();
    base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);
}

protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Customer>()
                .HasOne(cus => cus.Category)
                .WithMany(cat => cat.Customers)
                .HasForeignKey(nameof(Customer.CategoryId));
    modelBuilder.Entity<CustomerCategory>()
                .HasKey(e => e.CategoryId);
}
```

The exception is thrown when `db.SaveChanges()` is called in this snippet:

```
public static void AddCustomer()
{
    using (DataContext db = new())
    {
        try
        {
            Guid cat1Guid = new Guid("FA754EE8-B343-4E0B-9A11-AA066E4678C0");
            CustomerCategory category = db.CustomerCategories.Find(cat1Guid);
            Customer customer = new();
            customer.FileAs = "Fred-1";
            category.Customers.Add(customer);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        { }
    }
}
```

How do I add a member to a virtual collection using Entity Framework Core?

Comment: First remove `catch (Exception ex){ }` and never use it. Hiding exceptions doesn't make problems go away, it means you can't fix them. Second, post the actual full exception text, not just the message. I suspect you got a DbConcurrencyException. That's thrown when, as the text says, some other connection modified the entity between the time it was loaded and the time it was saved. Third, you didn't post the tables' schema (the CREATE TABLE statements, foreign key constraints), so one has to guess what's going on

Comment: My (pretty confident) guess - you never added `Customer` to the database, so you can't just add a relation to it  in `Category.Customers`. The call `category.Customers.Add(customer);` adds an entry to `CategoryCustomers`. To do that, it needs a valid related entry in the `Customers` table but none exist at this point. Add the customer before calling `SaveChanges` with `db.Customers.Add(customer);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, never use `catch(Exception exc){}`. This only makes problems harder to find and solve.

Add the new Customer object to the database before storing the changes. Set the category on the new customer object instead of going the other way round :

```
Customer customer = new();
customer.FileAs = "Fred-1";
customer.Category=category;
db.Customers.Add(customer);

db.SaveChanges();
```

You could avoid loading the category entirely by setting the `CategoryID` directly :

```
using DataContext db = new();
Guid cat1Guid = new Guid("FA754EE8-B343-4E0B-9A11-AA066E4678C0");
Customer customer = new() 
{
    CategoryID=cat1Guid,
    FileAs = "Fred-1"
};
db.Customers.Add(customer);
db.SaveChanges();
```

The call `category.Customers.Add(customer);` tells EF that the two entities are related, it doesn't create a new related entity. On the client side EF has no way of knowing whether `Customer` is a new or existing object, *especially* as it has a non-default ID. Did that call just ask EF to update a `Customer`'s category or insert a new one? There's no way to know.